# using pthread_setschedparam shows negative priorities on threads in htop

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I have the following set up in /etc/security/limits.conf on a centOS version 6.5 kernel 3.4.102-1 custom build for x86_64

```
*             -       rtprio          99
```

When I run the code below for a test code named PThreadAffinity below shows the threads the process and the priority (scroll right to see the tree). Why are the priorities not showing up as specified in the code?  Meaning the priorities assigned to the threads below in the main() are 39, 1, 20, and 2. Although in htop they show as -3, -21, -2, and -40.

```
30009 bjackfly   20   0  303M  1036   864 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │  │        └─ ./PThreadAffinity     
30013 bjackfly   -3   0  303M  1036   864 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │  │           ├─ ./PThreadAffinity  
30012 bjackfly  -21   0  303M  1036   864 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │  │           ├─ ./PThreadAffinity  
30011 bjackfly   -2   0  303M  1036   864 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │  │           ├─ ./PThreadAffinity  
30010 bjackfly  -40   0  303M  1036   864 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │  │           └─ ./PThreadAffinity
```

The sources:

```
       #include <thread>
       #include <pthread.h>
       #include <sstream>
       #include <cstring>
       #include <iostream>
       #include <stdexcept>

       std::string schedAttrAsStr(const int aPolicy, const sched_param &aParam) {
           std::stringstream ss;
           ss << ((aPolicy == SCHED_FIFO)  ? "SCHED_FIFO" :
                   (aPolicy == SCHED_RR)    ? "SCHED_RR" :
                   (aPolicy == SCHED_OTHER) ? "SCHED_OTHER" :
                   "???")
               << " @ " << aParam.sched_priority;
           return ss.str();
       }

       void createManaged(std::string aName, int aCpuNum, int aPriority, int aPolicy) { 
           cpu_set_t cpus;
           CPU_ZERO(&cpus);
           CPU_SET(aCpuNum, &cpus);
           int err;
           if((err = pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpus)) != 0)  {
               std::ostringstream os;
               os << "ERROR: Could not set affinity for cpu " << aCpuNum << "\n";
               std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;
           }

           // check if we have an exsiting schedule parameter
           sched_param oldParam;
           int oldPolicy;
           if(pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), &oldPolicy, &oldParam) == 0) {
               std::ostringstream os;
               os << "Threader old param for " << aName << " is " << schedAttrAsStr(oldPolicy, oldParam) << "\n"; 
           }


           sched_param param;
           memset(&param,0,sizeof(param));
           param.sched_priority = aPriority;
           if (aPriority > sched_get_priority_max(aPolicy)  || aPriority < sched_get_priority_min(aPolicy) ) { 
               std::ostringstream os;
               os << "Priority: " << aPriority << " is out of range for Policy: " << schedAttrAsStr(aPolicy, param)  << "\n";
               std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;
               throw std::runtime_error(os.str().c_str());
           }

           int ret = pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), aPolicy, &param);
           if(ret != 0) { 
               std::ostringstream os;
               std::cout << " Failed to set scheduler parameters for: " << aName << "\n";
               os << os.str() << std::endl;
               throw std::runtime_error(os.str().c_str());
           }
           else 
           {
               std::ostringstream os;
               os  << "Threader successfully set scheduler parameters for " << aName << " thread to " << schedAttrAsStr(aPolicy, param) <<
   "\n";
               std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;;
           }

           // Verify new
           if(pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), &oldPolicy, &oldParam) == 0)  { 
               std::ostringstream os;
               os << "Threader new param for " << aName << " is " << schedAttrAsStr(oldPolicy, oldParam) << "\n";
               std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;
           }
           else { 
               std::ostringstream os;
               os << " Threader Failed to get new parameters for: " << aName << "\n";
               std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;
           }
       };

       void runData(int aThreshold, std::string aName, int aCpuNum, int aPriority, int aPolicy) { 
           createManaged(aName,aCpuNum,aPriority,aPolicy);
           std::chrono::milliseconds timespan(aThreshold);      
           std::this_thread::sleep_for(timespan);

           std::ostringstream os;
           os << "Done Processing ThreadID: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
           std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;
       }

       int main() { 
           std::thread thr1(runData,900000,"Thread1",1,39,SCHED_FIFO);
           std::thread thr2(runData,900000,"Thread2",2,1,SCHED_FIFO);
           std::thread thr3(runData,900000,"Thread3",3,20,SCHED_FIFO);
           std::thread thr4(runData,900000,"Thread4",4,2,SCHED_FIFO);

           thr1.join();
           thr2.join();
           thr3.join();
           thr4.join();
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** - `procfs` reports real-time priorities as 1-`prio`, but your code is actually working correctly.

This is mostly because of an intricacy of the `/proc` filesystem.

First, you have your priority mapping backward (look at the process IDs in htop's output). The real mapping is as follows:

```
Thread1: Prio 39, reported -40
Thread2: Prio 1 , reported -2
Thread3: Prio 20, reported -21
Thread4: Prio 2 , reported -3
```

`htop` gets its information from a file called `stat` under each process' `procfs` entry, e.g. your thread's information would be read from `/proc/30010/stat`. In the [manpage for `procfs`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) is the following:

> /proc/[pid]/stat
>   Status information about the process. This is used by ps(1). It is defined in /usr/src/linux/fs/proc/array.c.
>
> ...
>
> (18) (Explanation for Linux 2.6) For processes running a real-time scheduling policy (policy below; see sched_setscheduler(2)), this is the negated scheduling priority, minus one; that is, a number in the range -2 to -100, corresponding to real-time priorities 1 to 99. For processes running under a non-real-time scheduling policy, this is the raw nice value (setpriority(2)) as represented in the kernel. The kernel stores nice values as numbers in the range 0 (high) to 39 (low), corresponding to the user-visible nice range of -20 to 19.